# Pivot with mode of service time values

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, mode

I have table like this:

```
ApplicationName    ServiceName    Time
Application        Service1       1
Application        Service1       1
Application        Service1       1
Application        Service1       2
Application        Service1       3
Application        Service2       2
Application        Service2       2
Application        Service2       1
Application        Service2       1
Application        Service2       2
Application        Service2       2
Application        Service3       1
Application        Service3       3
Application        Service3       3
```

And I want to make Pivot table like this one:

```
ApplicationName    ServiceName    Time(mode)
Application        Service1       1
Application        Service2       2
Application        Service3       3
```

So that the Time is mode value (most frequent value of specific service)
How to do it in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a pivot-table layout, you can get it like this.  Note that the formula is an array formula, entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.  Then just drag the formula down to the Service2 and Service3 cells.  [image]

Someone smarter than me may come up with it; but I've been unable to use "MODE" in a pivot table calculated field.  I suspect it's because you'd have to involve an array of values in the pivot table calculated field -- which may not be supported.